# Is Fastled.io library suitable for SMD50500 led strip?

Tags: arduino-uno, c, rgb-led

I was looking for a ready to use library to control my SMD5050 color led strip, and I stumbled across FASTLED.IO library , but after reading trough their website I didn't find anywhere the support for SMD5050 color LED strip. Does anyone knows another "ready to use" animation library? Are FASTLED.IO suitable anyway?
Thanks

Comment: SMD5050 is just a shape of LED. It's a surface mount 5mm x 5mm package. What *actual* LED strip do you have?

Comment: @Majenko actually I forgot..I bought it one year ago...I looked on the strip but there's nothing writed on it...how can I understand it?

Comment: Do you have 4 connections at the end: +12V/R/G/B ? Or do you have 3 connections:  +5V/DAT/GND?

Comment: @Majenko yep...four connections

Comment: Then you can't animate it. You can just set the colour of the strip.

Comment: You'd wire it somewhat like this: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/rgb-led-strips-with-arduino

Comment: @Majenko I know they are not addressable but I thought to use FASTLED to make just simple color fade animation.. pulsing..buoncing..easing functions and so on..

Comment: FastLED is for addressable LEDs.

Comment: @Majenko They are wired in the way you showed me

Comment: You don't need a library to set the colours - just set the PWM outputs to the levels you want. It's up to you to "animate" it by changing those values.

Comment: @Majenko I was thinking there were other library with already made function like those http://easings.net/it

Comment: Not that I have ever come across. Arduino LED animation libraries are aimed at animating large numbers of individual LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. FastLED is for addressable LEDs (like the WS2812B). Yours aren't addressable. You just need to set the colour you want with the PWM outputs of your Arduino. Changing the PWM values is not hard and you don't need a library to do it for you.

Comment: you are right...changing PWM value is not hardthe hard..will be achieving some of this fade functions http://easings.net/it

Comment: I am sure you are up to the task of writing the ones you want. If you have a mathematical formula you can easily calculate the colour to use at any one point in time. Otherwise simple CLUTs would be easy to implement.